# Relative output path in MSBuild xml

Tags: msbuild, wix

I'm currently working on a `WiX` project. I want to use a relative output path for a `.csproj` inside my `.wixproj` file.

When including a project it automatically creates a `ProjectReference` like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
    <!-- Then some properties like
         Name
         Project (GUID)
         Private, etc. -->
</ItemGroup>
```

The output path of my `.csproj` is in another folder `..\Output\MyProjectOutput\` for example but it is subject to change. 
Is there any way to access the relative target directory of this `ItemGroup` in another `ItemGroup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProjectReference` creates a few useful variables that take advantage of conventions. (If it didn't, it would have build your project just to see where the output folders are.) Your project is not following those conventions.

To accommodate the potential for change, you'd have to create your own extractor for your .csproj. Or, have your .csproj leave a signpost in a designated place, perhaps generating a .wxi for itself.